# Javascript to jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a pure JavaScript file the past days. It's a fully operational BlackJack game. However i was told to try and use as much jquery as possible on my existing file. So I can understand the basics of jQuery.

Things like

`$("#Result").empty();`

and

`$("#hit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
 $("#hit").removeAttr("disabled");`

all work fine. But i have a problem with this one for example:

```
function player_blackjack() {
    $("#Result").text("BlackJack!");
    var bet = parseInt($("#bet").val());
    var bank = parseInt(document.getElementById("Bank").innerHTML);
    bank = bank + (bet * 2.5);
    document.getElementById("Bank").innerHTML = bank;
    start_game_buttons();
}
```

The first lines work, all except the `var bank` and the line above `start_game_buttons();`, thats why they are still javascript written.

If i change the var bank line to this one:

`var bank = parseInt($("#Bank").html);`

It just doesn't work. When i run this and make myself get a blackjack ill get a `NaN` where the bank should be. I also tried:

`var bank = parseInt($("#Bank").val());`

Im basically just trying whatever i can find, but since i can't figure it out im trying my luck here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `html()` is a method, not a property. You have to call it: `var bank = parseInt($("#Bank").html());`

Comment: You should be using `parseFloat` and not `parseInt`. And you probably want to use `text()` instead of `html()`.

Comment: @epascarello  What is exactly the difference between text and html if you can choose them both? And why should i use parsefloat instead of parseint?

Comment: Test out: `parseInt("5.55", 10);` and  `parseFloat("5.55");` in your browser and you tell me why need to use it.

Comment: @epascarello Ok, fair enough. Thanks for this tip! That would've caused lot of problems in the long run. Also why should i use text instead of html?

Comment: because it is just the text...

Comment: @epascarello Should i also use it in my file, since those divs (div id player, dealer, etc) are all empty except for what im placing in them. Is it just bad practice for using .html like this?

Comment: Just developer preference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the `()` after the `html` method, it should be:

```
var bank = parseInt($("#Bank").html());
```

Although, why are you using `parseInt` on an `html()` call? If this is an `input` -- use `.val()`

Comment: It doesn't work when i remove the parseInt. Say my bank is 100, i bet 1. Click start and get blackjack. The bank will show me this: 992.5. (99 being the leftover bank and 2.5 what i won: bank = bank + bet * 2.5) | It's because bet is an input field, but bank is a label.

Comment: This solved it the way! (I feel stupid for this kind of mistakes) I'll accept your answer when i can